# apply best fitted discount package on items automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logic

I have created some discount packages:

```
Package1(Item1,Item2,Item5) Discount-5%.
Package2(Item2,Item5,Item8) Discount-8% 
Package3(Item1,Item2) Discount3%.
```

When a Person buy Items Online(for Ex. he buys Item1,Item2,Item5, Item10), while I show him the total price, I need to apply the best fitted discount on the items automatically.

In the above case, two discounts would be applicable on said selection, however *Package1 Discount is best as it give a person max benefit*... so this I need apply this automatically.

Is there anyone who came across this type of scenario or anyone who could help me?

```
DiscountID DiscountName ItemIds Disc%

1 Package1 1,2,5 5
2 Package2 2,3,5 8
3 Package3 1,2 3
```

I have all the ItemId with me, which a Person selected. Now need to apply best fit discount..

Appreciating your help/ guidance.

Comment: How many packages do you have?

Comment: In a given order, can 1 unit of an item only be assigned to one package?

Comment: If someone is buying 10 Item1s, 10 Item2s and 10 Item5s, can they get a Package1 discount on the entire order?

Comment: Can more than one package be applied to the same order?

Comment: One Item can be assigned to only one Discount.. we can apply more that one dicount package to one order(Num Of Items) but Single item can avail more than 1 Discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-- Test tables
CREATE TABLE #Package(Name varchar(50), Discount decimal(10,2))
CREATE TABLE #PackageItem(PackageName varchar(50), ProductName varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #ShoppingCart(ProductName varchar(50))

-- Test data
INSERT INTO #Package VALUES ('Package1', 0.05)
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package1', 'Item1')
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package1', 'Item2')
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package1', 'Item5')
INSERT INTO #Package VALUES ('Package2', 0.08)
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package2', 'Item1')
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package2', 'Item5')
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package2', 'Item8')
INSERT INTO #Package VALUES ('Package3', 0.03)
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package3', 'Item1')
INSERT INTO #PackageItem VALUES ('Package3', 'Item2')

INSERT INTO #ShoppingCart VALUES ('Item1')
INSERT INTO #ShoppingCart VALUES ('Item2')
INSERT INTO #ShoppingCart VALUES ('Item5')
INSERT INTO #ShoppingCart VALUES ('Item10')

SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    (
    -- Join #ShoppingCart with PackageItem and count matched rows
    SELECT      #Package.Name, #Package.Discount,
                COUNT(#Package.Name) AS [Count]
    FROM        #ShoppingCart
    LEFT JOIN   #PackageItem 
                ON #PackageItem.ProductName = #ShoppingCart.ProductName
    LEFT JOIN   #Package ON #Package.Name = #PackageItem.PackageName
    GROUP BY    #Package.Name, #Package.Discount
        ) A
JOIN
        (
    -- Count how many products each package have
    SELECT      #Package.Name,
                COUNT(#Package.Name) AS [Count]
    FROM        #Package
    LEFT JOIN   #PackageItem ON #Package.Name = #PackageItem.PackageName
    GROUP BY    #Package.Name, #Package.Discount
        ) B
-- if same package contains same number of products, pick it
-- (so you can't have a same item twice in your cart;
--  but you probably already have a quantity column)
ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.[Count] = B.[Count]
-- just greater discount matters
ORDER BY A.Discount DESC

-- Clear test stuff
DROP TABLE #Package
DROP TABLE #PackageItem
DROP TABLE #ShoppingCart
```

Comment: Hi Rubbens, thanks a lot for you response, your code works fine, however in case when Item selection is like, where 2 packages will be applicable ..it fails.. for eg., Selection (Item1, Item2,Item3,Item5,Item8) and Packages are Package1(Item1,Item2)-5% Package2(Item3,Item5)-6%. in this case without overlapping Package1 and Package2 would be applicable on selection.. Here it fails. Do U have a way to over come this week point... 
I am Deeply thankful to you for your time and efforts..thanks !

Comment: I didn't understood your comment; running code above with your new sample data returned package2 (6%) which seems correct. Did you tried to remove that `TOP 1`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply each set of purchased items to each package, either returning the discount %, or zero, if they don't qualify, then query those results for the max discount from your set of packages.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems like this is an instance of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

[This paper](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/ioerger/ICAI04-linli1.pdf) seems to address a similar problem to yours.

**Brute Force Solution**

One brute force solution would be to apply every valid combination of discount packages to the order.

Picture a tree where, for a given node, each ancestor represents a discount package that has already been applied to the order, and each of its children represent a valid discount package that can be applied to the remaining items in the order.

A node is a leaf when no more packages can be applied to the order.

I wouldn't recommend this if you have a large number of items and more than 1 discount package being offered.